# What is wrong with my computer case air circulation. My CPU goes up to 80 degrees

Tags: cpu, fan

So I assembled this computer and I think I made a mistake with the fan positioning.
My CPU temp goes up to 80 degrees and I have to open the case and put a fan under the case to bring it down. **It comes down to 45-50 when I do this.**

P.S. Could this temperature have already damaged the CPU? It might have operated for a total of 100-200 hours at this temperature is the past 2 months. I built it exactly 2 months ago.

[image]

I have a new ASUS Rampage IV and a Intel Core-i7 3820, I use the recommended fan made by intel for the CPU.

[image]

Comment: If it gets that hot, then first check the obvious: The CPU cooling itself. Is there a thermal pad (with plastic protection removed!) or thermal paste?

Comment: yes there was silicon on the CPU fan when I bought it

Comment: The stock Intel fan isn't really that good; make sure all of the mounting pins are firmly pressed down. Actually, it 80C isn't that surprising at all: you have two *hot* GPUs right under it. Do the GPUs vent air outside of the case? Edit: Also, manage the cables a bit better for improved airflow.

Comment: First I agree with the above, The mounting and goop on the CPU sync would be first priority.Cool pic, which direction is the PSU fan (down and out I assume)?  Some people would say you are creating a slight vaccume pressure, when you have 4out and only 1 in, if it is a closed case VS a grilled or more open style of case that is more popular today. FANOPT might be better off bringing in cool air to the cpu heatsync area.  Your using a stock intel sync? because there are even cheapo syncs that will be "better" but mostly needed when overclocking, as the stock is sufficient when not overclocking.

Comment: Yes the stock intel sync but I bought it on eBay and the silicon thermal paste was already exposed to air I remember accidentally touching it.

Comment: Let's just get this question out of the way for clarity: Have you overclocked the CPU or is it running at the stock speed?

Comment: @Fopedush I did originally but since it was getting hot I put it back at  3.60Ghz

Comment: @Rain My case is small so the GPUs are right under eachother and it is not clear in the pic but the fans are so big it is only a few milimeters from touching the other GPU and the PSU is right under the second one so they don't get to vent very well.

Comment: @Psycogeek The PSU fan is pointed towards the outside, it is under pointing out and there are holes there on the case. I assume it is blowing out since that is how PSU's blow.

Comment: One more thing when I open the case and put one of those laptop fan pads that you put your laptop under the case it It comes down to 45-50. It also helps When I put it blowing in right when the intake is on the outside. The problem is I don't have any room in the case to put fans except on the top where they are to blow in and I don't think it is a good idea to put the intake there.

Comment: I thought the LGA family didn't come with a stock heat sink. And wiring management is a good idea. What case *is* that? It looks a little small

Comment: I think your top fans make things worse. With so many fans blowing out, you'll have negative pressure in your case, which the GPU fans have to fight. If they lose that battle, then hot air from your GPU will get sucked into the CPU heat sink. However, my bet is that your main problem is that your heat sink isn't mated properly to the CPU. Maybe it's not perfectly flat, maybe there's a hair in there, maybe there's too little pressure.

Comment: You have an imbalance of incoming air versus outflow air.  There are a lot of fans to extract the hot air.  But your case has only one forced intake for cool air.  The amount of hot air extracted is limited by the amount of (cool) air let into the case (otherwise the case will implode). The case needs more air intakes.  Since the CPU operates at reasonable temps with the open case, don't bother with all the "fixes" for the CPU heatsink.  The problem is mentioned in your title: air circulation or air flow.

Comment: Try a simple test: reverse the flow of the CPU fan by flipping it over, so that it pulls air IN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you are either having problems with thermal throttling or are overclocking.

[Warning: Overclocking can damage your components]

Make sure that if you are overclocking that you go up in increments on the clock speed and Voltage. Test run it at each new speed to see if stable. Overclocking generates extra heat and suitable precautions ought to be taken before embarking [go to 5].

1. Improve your airflow by tidying your cables. Proper cable management will improve the passage of air through your case.
2. Use decent thermal paste as the stuff that is on stock fans is okay but you can get better performance with the aftermarket stuff.
3. Crank up the fans; if they are running very slow the air will not be displaced quick enough to cool the ambient case temperature [Warning this can get very noisy and is not recommended for HTPC setups go to 5].
4. Clean your case. A build-up of dust within your case will cause your components to overheat. If your case does not have filters then a good clean will help. Most people tend to keep their PCs on the floor under their desk where airflow is not optimum.
5. To achieve a better result, change your current Air Cooled CPU Cooler. There are a number of sealed liquid cooled CPU Coolers on the market at very reasonable prices which would reduce the heat from your processor. If you can afford it go for a fully blown liquid cooled system which could also cool your GPU or refrigerated PC case, both of which are expensive.

Article on CPU Coolers:
http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/processors/best-cpu-cooler-12-top-coolers-reviewed-and-rated-956968/2#articleContent

Not sure if anyone is still making them but here is an example of the refrigerated PC case:
http://www.trustedreviews.com/Asetek-VapoChill-XE-II-Refrigerated-PC-Case_Peripheral_review

If you want to get extreme:
http://www.liquidnitrogenoverclocking.com/vortex_f6.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Two things I could think of:

1. Make sure you don't have too much silicon paste on the CPU. Lots of HP laptops at work had this issue so we had to actually remove silicon.
2. Computers these days seem to have vents that blow the air out of CPUs directly out of the box. Might want to look into vents.

Comment: Looks like he's got three fans very close to the CPU all exhausting air -- shouldn't need any more than that.

Comment: I hope you mean `silicone`, not `silicon`... :D

Answer (score 0):

From seeing OP's diagram, I would say switch the one top fan nearest the front of the case to blow air out of the case.  I had my 2 fans on top set up like yours and then was informed that, you still get air circulation.

Mine were set up to blow out of the case, but I think by doing that for both fans, it puts more strain on those fans as they are trying to pull out all the heat, whereas if the fan above the processor is blowing into the case, and the other top fan is blowing out of the case, you'll have that air circulating.